# How to use SOAP::Lite' https protocol to implement a web service client based on certificate?

Tags: perl, soap, https, certificate, soaplite

Already , I have a remote web service service ,and I have to implement a perl client using https protocol ,based on certificate Authentication，any suggestion?Does SOAP::Lite have such support?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's supported, see [`useragent` attribute](http://p3rl.org/SOAP%3a%3aSchema#useragent-LWP%3a%3aUserAgent).